# CDK Unit test failing when I can see a matched resource created

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

My CDK unit test is failing, I am trying to test that my parameter has been built correctly. Here is the CDK code in my actual stack

```
    const serviceUrl = StringParameter.valueForStringParameter(
      scope,
      `${StackConfiguration.PARAM}${StackConfiguration.HYPHEN}${StackConfiguration.environmentKey}${StackConfiguration.HYPHEN}${StackConfiguration.SERVICE_URL_PARAM_NAME}`
    );
```

Here is my test that is failing

```
    expect(stack).toMatch({
      Parameters: {
        RefParameter: {
          Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>',
          Default: 'myparameter-unit-test-service-url',
        },
      },
    });
```

failure message

```
● Test suite failed to run

    Template comparison produced unacceptable match
```

Here is the CFT that I can see being generated

```
        "SsmParameterValuemyparameterunittestserviceurlC96584B6F00A464EAD1953AFF4B05118Parameter": {
          "Type": "AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>",
          "Default": "myparameter-unit-test-service-url"
        },
```

Comment: Please provide the code you want to test.

Comment: I did, the first block of code is what I want to test. It is CDK code it will generate a cloudformation template